# Apply and custom function to add calculated fields to dataframe in R

Tags: r, lapply

I've browsed R for an hour or so trying to find an answer to a problem I'm having and I can't work it out based on the answers I've seen so far.  I need to add a list of calculated values into a new column within a dataframe.  I've tried doing this with an if statement but was having no luck, I've been trying to complete this exercise with the apply function and a custom function.

Theoretically this is my data:

```
a <- 1:5
b <- 1:5
c <- 1:5
 
df <- data.frame(a,b,c) 

  a b c
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5
```

This is the function that I wish to embed within the lapply function.

```
func <- function(x){
  (((x/1000)*b)+c)
}
```

When I try and run this:

```
lapply(df, function(x) {(((x/1000)*b)+c)})
```

I get the following output:

```
$a
[1] 1.001 2.004 3.009 4.016 5.025

$b
[1] 1.001 2.004 3.009 4.016 5.025

$c
[1] 1.001 2.004 3.009 4.016 5.025
```

Which I'm sure is right, but it's not what I'm looking for, what I'm trying to generate is column D, which would be (((a/1000)*b)+c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply this?

```
a <- 1:5
b <- 1:5
c <- 1:5

df <- data.frame(a,b,c) 
(df$d <- ((df$a/1000)*df$b)+df$c)
```

Comment: Yep, all the parentheses aren't really necessary either. `df$d <- with(df, a/1000 * b + c )` for instance.